# Get Gazebo Mesh size

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,
I was wondering if there is a way to get the mesh size of a Gazebo model within ros through a service call.
If not, what would be the best way to write such a service

Basically if you have such a model

```
 <!-- office walls -->
  <model:physical name="wall_1_model">
    <xyz>0 -5 1</xyz>
    <rpy>0.0 0.0 0.0</rpy>
    <static>true</static>
    <body:box name="wall_1_body">
      <geom:box name="wall_1_geom">
        <mesh>default</mesh>
        <size>10 .2 2</size>
        <visual>
          <size>10 .2 2</size>
          <material>Gazebo/Green</material>
          <mesh>unit_box</mesh>
        </visual>
      </geom:box>
    </body:box>
  </model:physical>
```

I want to get the size <10 .2 2> from the mesh section.

Thanks
Chris

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35425/get-gazebo-mesh-size/) by [Christian](https://answers.ros.org/users/2513/christian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2012-05-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, so I found a solution. To get access to the gazebo shapes you have to create a Gazebo Plugin. There is a tutorial on [Gazebo](http://gazebosim.org/) how to do that.

After that you can access Model->Body->Geom->Shape->BoxShape.

```
    gazebo::physics::ModelPtr model = this->world_->GetModel(req.model_name);
    if (!model)
    {
      ROS_ERROR("GetModelProperties: model [%s] does not exist",req.model_name.c_str());
      res.success = false;
      res.status_message = "GetModelProperties: model does not exist";
      return false;
    }
    else
    {

  // get model parent name
  gazebo::physics::ModelPtr parent_model = boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<gazebo::physics::Model>(model->GetParent());

  // get list of child bodies, geoms
  for (unsigned int i = 0 ; i < model->GetChildCount(); i ++)
  {
    gazebo::physics::LinkPtr body = boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<gazebo::physics::Link>(model->GetChild(i));
    if (body)
    {
      // get list of geoms
      for (unsigned int j = 0; j < body->GetChildCount() ; j++)
      {
        gazebo::physics::CollisionPtr geom = boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<gazebo::physics::Collision>(body->GetChild(j));

        if (geom)
        { 
          res.geom_name = geom->GetName();
          gazebo::physics::ShapePtr shape(geom->GetShape ());
          
          if (shape->HasType (gazebo::physics::Base::BOX_SHAPE))
          {
            gazebo::physics::BoxShape *box = static_cast<gazebo::physics::BoxShape*>(shape.get ());
            math::Vector3 tmp_size = box->GetSize ();
            geometry_msgs::Vector3 size;
            size.x = tmp_size.x;
            size.y = tmp_size.y;
            size.z = tmp_size.z;
            
            res.size = size;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  res.success = true;
  res.status_message = "GetModelProperties: got properties";
  return true;
}
return true;
```

---

Originally posted by [Christian](https://answers.ros.org/users/2513/christian/) with karma: 56 on 2012-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4